# Unable to Install SharePoint 2016 in Multi Farm Mode

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, server-farm, sharepoint-farm, farm-admin

I have SQL server 2014SP1 in Server "A", And SharePoint 2016 in Server "B".
In configuration wizard at the creation of the database , When I give Server "A" database name and username.I get error **"Invalid Username"** .
Can anyone let em know how can I solve this

Answer (score 0):

How you are entering the user name?

You have to make sure couple of things

- it should be a domain user.domain\username
- ur servers are connected to domain.

Invalid user name mean either u are not entering as domain user or their is typo in ur user name or domain..

Comment: Holding same domains .But finding no luck,Can you guide me with any blog post